# Chart.js building dynamic charts, JSON data parsing issue

Tags: jquery, json, twitter-bootstrap, chart.js

I'm building a dynamically generated graphs using [chartjs](/questions/tagged/chartjs), [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery), [json](/questions/tagged/json), [mustache.js](/questions/tagged/mustache.js)& [twitter-bootstrap](/questions/tagged/twitter-bootstrap).

All the data is within the [json](/questions/tagged/json)file and I use Mustache as templating engine to display each item.
Building the graphs dynamically from [json](/questions/tagged/json).

The issue I have is that the dataset that's passed from [json](/questions/tagged/json)into the charts object is rendered as one element, basically it's treated as string.

I've further used split function to separate each value but still when I log the data, I see the numbers are wrapped within quotes!

Not sure how I can get rid of the quotes and/or how to pass the correct data.

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'get',
  url: "/data/portfolio.json",
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function(data) {
    $(data.portfolio).each(function(index, value) {
      addCharts(value);
      renderMyCharts(value.chartLabels, value.chartData, value.order);
    })
  }
});
```

**JSON**

```
{
  "portfolio": [{
    "title": "MesoDoc 411",
    "description": "",
    "link": "http://www.mesodoc411.com",
    "image": "/images/portfolio/mesodoc.png",
    "url": "/portfolio/",
    "order": "30",
    "chartLabels": "'HTML5', 'CSS' ",
    "chartData": "30 99"
  }]
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
function renderMyCharts(chartLabels, chartData, order) {
  // This function grabs the parameters from the JSON File
  // parses the chart data per Project
  var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart" + order);
  console.log(ctx);
  var kChart = "myChart" + order;

  console.log(kChart);

  console.log("passed chartLabels " + chartLabels);
  console.log("passed chartData " + chartData);
  console.log("Data type is : " + typeof chartData);

  var res = chartData.split(" ");

  console.log("string splitted  " + res);
  console.log("Data type is : " + typeof res);
  var kChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'pie',
    data: {
      labels: [chartLabels],
      datasets: [{
        label: 'Techs  ',
        data: [res],
        backgroundColor: [
          'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
          'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
          'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
          'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
          'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
          'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
        ],
        borderColor: [
          'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
          'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
          'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
          'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
          'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
          'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
        ],
        borderWidth: 1
      }]
    },
    options: {
      legend: {
        display: true,
        labels: {
          fontColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)'
        }
      }

    }
  });
  console.log(kChart.data);
}
```

In this code if I pass 2 values manually to data like `data: [76, 12]` the chart displays properly, but `.data: [res]` does NOT, in console I see:

```
data:Array(1)
0:Array(2)
0:"30"
1:"99"
length:2
```

But it should:

```
data:Array(1)
    0:Array(2)
    0:30
    1:99
    length:2
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [Array#map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

```js
var chartData = "30 99";
var res = chartData.split(" ");
console.log("Before:");
console.log(res);

console.log("After:");
console.log(res.map(function(x) {return x * 1;}));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  top: 0!important;
}
```

```js
var chartData = "30, 99";
var res = chartData.split(", ");
console.log("Before:");
console.log(res);

console.log("After:");
console.log(res.map(function(x) {return x * 1;}));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  top: 0!important;
}
```

You need to use:

```
var kChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'pie',
    data: {
      labels: [chartLabels],
      datasets: [{
        label: 'Techs  ',
        data: data: res.map(function(x) {return x * 1;}),
```

Comment: thanks but arraymap still creates an object, which charts doesn't like! I need to somehow pass comma separated values to the data[] array, but when I try passing  charData = "12, 34", it considers that ONE string....

Comment: If you pass this: `data: [12, 34]` works? Then...: `data: res.map(function(x) {return x * 1;})`?

Answer (score 0):

The point of data formats such as JSON, XML, etc is that you don't have to write so much custom code for parsing/serialising data. In that sense you're not using JSON fully. I don't know exactly what your situation is and whether you have control of the JSON structure. If not, you'll just have to use Danny's answer or something equivalent. If you do, change it to this:

```
"chartData": [30, 99]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
data: res.map(function(x) {return x * 1;})
```

did the trick !  Thanks Danny !